# Why does my multisig `approve_as_multi` extrinsic has failed with `InsufficientBalance` error?

Tags: extrinsic, balances, multisig

In this [link](https://westend.subscan.io/extrinsic/11417201-2) you can find my multisig `approve_as_multi` extrinsic and see the `InsufficientBalance` error.

Does the balance error here refers to the **sender** (signatory) balance or the **multisig** address balance? Because the balance of my sender account has 0,5 WND and I was thinking it is enough.

How much balance do I need or how do I calculate it ?

Answer (score 2):

In this [link](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/2871#issuecomment-732701654) it is explained that the sender (one of the signatories) of the `approve_as_multi` tx needs to have enough balance to enact this tx.

To calculate how much balance the sender needs to enact this tx, you need to check the following :

1. The formula of calculation is described [here](https://docs.rs/pallet-multisig/latest/pallet_multisig/enum.Call.html#variant.approve_as_multi) and I quote it below :

> Payment: DepositBase will be reserved if this is the first approval,
> plus threshold times DepositFactor. It is returned once this dispatch
> happens or is cancelled.

2. Then you will need to query in polkadot-js apps (connected in Westend) -> Developer -> Chain State -> the Multisig constants : depositFactor, depositBase, maxSignatories (as shown in the screenshot below)

   I already did it for you and the values are the following :

   - const multisig.depositFactor = 1,600,000,000
   - const multisig.depositBase = 1,004,400,000,000
   - const multisig.maxSignatories = 100 (but in your case is 2 Max signatories)

[image]

3. Additionally, you need to take into account the base units in Westend as found [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/566a403be1277612f413136d9febe5efaabcf417/runtime/westend/constants/src/lib.rs#L28)

This results in the following formula :
(1004400000000+2*1600000000)/1000000000000=1,0076 WND

In conclusion, the sender account needs at least 1,0076 WND in their balance to enact this tx.