# Will the event pairs `NewMultisig` <> `Reserved` and `MultisigExecuted` <> `Unreserved` always be emitted during a multisig transaction?

Tags: events, multisig

I would like to correctly monitor the events that are related to multisig transactions and I was wondering if I should always expect the following event pairs :

- `NewMultisig` <> `Reserved`
- `MultisigExecuted` <> `Unreserved`

to be triggered. Also, will the reservation amount always be the same?

Answer (score 1):

The event pairs will/should always happen one after another when we have a `NewMultisig` or a `MultisigExecuted` event.

More specifically these events will happen in the following order as we check the code in substrate :

- When a new multisig tx is created :

  - This means that we have the 1st approval so the function [approve_as_multi](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f318350b6410ef47e438aae24c0b4779373d0a7b/frame/multisig/src/lib.rs#L423) is called from the `Multisig` Pallet.
  - Then this function calls the [operate](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f318350b6410ef47e438aae24c0b4779373d0a7b/frame/multisig/src/lib.rs#L516) function and the reserve will happen either [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f318350b6410ef47e438aae24c0b4779373d0a7b/frame/multisig/src/lib.rs#L645) or [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f318350b6410ef47e438aae24c0b4779373d0a7b/frame/multisig/src/lib.rs#L648).
  - These functions will then trigger the event [Reserved](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8b2f5379653d9d741f666634ed7f751dd6870381/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L1794) from the balances pallet
  - Then you can see that the [NewMultisig](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f318350b6410ef47e438aae24c0b4779373d0a7b/frame/multisig/src/lib.rs#L662) event will be called after.
- When a multisig tx is executed :

  - This means that we have the last approval so the function [as_multi](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f318350b6410ef47e438aae24c0b4779373d0a7b/frame/multisig/src/lib.rs#L360) is called from the Multisig pallet.
  - Then this function again calls the [operate](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f318350b6410ef47e438aae24c0b4779373d0a7b/frame/multisig/src/lib.rs#L516) and the [unreserve](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f318350b6410ef47e438aae24c0b4779373d0a7b/frame/multisig/src/lib.rs#L573) functions.
  - This function will then trigger the event [Unreserved](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8b2f5379653d9d741f666634ed7f751dd6870381/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L1826) from the Balances pallet.
  - Last the event [MultisigExecuted](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f318350b6410ef47e438aae24c0b4779373d0a7b/frame/multisig/src/lib.rs#L576) is triggered after the unreserve.

*** The reservation amount is calculated based on the following formula :

> DepositBase will be reserved if this is the first approval, plus
> threshold times DepositFactor. It is returned once this dispatch
> happens or is cancelled.

and an example on how to calculate it in Westend is shown in detail this [post](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3506/234)