# How to use `asMultiThreshold1` within the multisig pallet

Tags: polkadot-js, westend, multisig

#### Aim

I would like to use the `asMultiThreshold1` extrinsic in the Extrinsic Tab to produce a multi-sig call to authorise a balance transfer from the multi-sig account `ABC` (made by Alice, Bob and Charlie) to the account `Stash 2`.

#### What I tried

I used Alice's account to dispatch the multi-sig call

[image]

This resulted in the following error:

[image]

Such error can be viewed [here](https://westend.subscan.io/extrinsic/12533740-2). I have enough balance to do such operation, I do not understand why the UI is saying the opposite.

#### What is unclear to me

As far as I understood the `asMultiThreshold1` option is used when only one approval is needed. To me it is unclear why I would need a multi-sig account with only one approval. Also, the UI does not let me to generate one as the minimum threshold I can choose is 2.

Answer (score 1):

The [as_multi_threshold_1](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/multisig/src/lib.rs#L267) function can be useful when you need to allow people to share an account with full permission to use it.

A real use case scenario could be for example a business that has a bank account and says "*any one of the 3 founders can authorize payments from this account*".

In that case you will need to have :

- A multisig with 3 signatories and threshold 1
- If one out of the three signatories signs, then the call is executed
- In this case `as_multi_threshold_1` should be used since no further approvals are needed (hence no need to use [approve_as_multi](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/multisig/src/lib.rs#L423) or [as_multi](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/multisig/src/lib.rs#L360)).

I can confirm that currently [Polkadot-js Apps](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/accounts) does not allow the creation of Multisig accounts with threshold lower than 2. This changed in this [p-js apps PR](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/3542) based on this reported [issue](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/3541) in the same repo. However there is still an [issue](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/3862) open that I think requests exactly that, allowing multisigs with threshold 1. I am not sure however what is the reason why it is still not implemented. Maybe you could add a comment in the repository, in the corresponding issue to ask that or even better submit a PR with the change & solution. It would certainly be a great contribution for the tool and the community.

In the meantime, if you would like to create a multisig with threshold 1 then you could also use [txwrapper-core](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core) which is a tool that Parity supports with new features and weekly updates. There is a detailed [Multisig](https://github.com/paritytech/txwrapper-core/tree/main/packages/txwrapper-examples/multisig) example that you can try out and change to see how it works.

Comment: Hi Dominique, thank for clarifying this. I was thinking I was using the function in a wrong way. I added a comment to the currently opened issue on this topic asking if it is possible to fix it or remove the functionality because the UI does not stop users from using non-working functions. This can lead to loss of real money if not using the testnet first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [reserve](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/multisig/src/lib.rs#L681) some tokens while using multi-sig.

Different configurations for different networks.

I'm not sure how much Westend needed. But try transfer more token to your account.

Comment: Maybe this post https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3506/234 is helpful

Comment: Hi @dominique and @AurevoirXavier, I definitely have enough WND to to the transactions. I am able to use the Extrinsic tab with `asMulti`, and do a multisig balance transfer with a multisig account with threshold=2. 

I am not able to successfully use the `asMultiThrshold1` function. To me is unclear if I need a multisig with threshold=1, since I am not able to set up one using the UI.